# Touchpad could not click

Tags: touchpad

When I installed Ubuntu gnome 16.04 Ltd, I found that touchpad doesn't work so well. I could scroll and move, but I couldn't click by click the touchpad. I have to click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The touch to click feature is disabled by default in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, you can enable it by selecting ***mouse and touchpad*** option in the ***System Settings***.